# Is there a way to view Game Center information on OS X?

Tags: macos, ios, game-center

Is there a way to view Game Center information, such as achievements or friends, on OS X (or any other desktop OS), or is Game Center only accessible from iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moment it only works on iOS. I would assume there will be plans at some point for Apple to release it to the Mac, however nothing has been mentioned publicly. Apple has also not provided any web interface for it, and I suspect if they do it will be part of iCloud.